# Myrrix: Recommending items to user that are similar to a group of other items

Tags: collaborative-filtering, myrrix

I know Myrrix can be used to recommend items to a user, and also to output items that are most similar to a group of other items. But can it be used for the combined task?

That is, given a user ID and a group of items, can I recommend items to that user with the constraint that the recommendations should also be similar to the specified group of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly,  but you can use an `IDRescorer` / `RescorerProvider` to multiply the scores for an item by, say, average similarity to your group of items. It would take some custom work.